# How to delete index in custom java connector

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have build a custom connector to get the data from a web service and then index it. The web service response returns only the data to be indexed.

I want to delete the documents from index which are not part of the web service response during the crawl but were added to the index in the last crawl.

Is there any way to achieve the above or can I flush the full index programmatically in the connector code and then add the recent content to the index.

Comment: You can't delete the complete index but do a full feed for your datasource which resets that part of the index. Which GSA Version and connector framework are you talking about ?

Comment: The GSA version is 7.4 and Connector Manager version is 3.4.0-RC1

Comment: You should definitely consider the new Connector Framework v4.1 for new connectors. It is available for all relevant GSA versions (7.2 upwards). I can't provide details when Google will end support of the old connector framework but I bet this will happen at a time when all of us can handle this the least ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Marged is correct.  A feed (which is what the connector can send to the GSA) of type full will purge the existing feed and replace it.  Otherwise, your connector is going to have to manage state and prune out documents as you decided.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marged and Michael for the help.. I guess i have to write the custom logic in connector to delete the data from index.

Comment: Just a note: this isn't an answer in the shape SO expects. If you found the solution copy the relevant code parts here, this will then create an answer the solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is exactly what happens when you send a "full" content feed. This is from the [documentation](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/gsa_doc_set/feedsguide/feedsguide.html#1074377):

> When the feedtype element is set to full for a content feed, the system deletes all the prior URLs that were associated with the data source. The new feed contents completely replace the prior feed contents. If the feed contains metadata, you must also provide content for each record; a full feed cannot push metadata alone. You can delete all documents in a data source by pushing an empty full feed.

Marged is correct that v4.x is the way to go in the future, but if you've already started this with the 3.x connector framework and you're happy with it there's no need to rush to upgrade it. All the related code is open source and 3.x won't disappear any time soon, there are too many 3rd party connectors based on it.